# Why the second array gets also the values from the first array

Tags: php, arrays

The first array is the correct product ids, but in the loop after the first array all product ids are added:

```
foreach ($cat_array_data as $cat_items) {

  // Foreach category id
  $cat_id_object =  $cat_items['cat_id'];
  $product_ids =  $cat_items['product_ids'];

 // display the correct product ids
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($product_ids);
  echo "</pre>";

  foreach ($product_ids as $single_product_id) {
    

   // add foreingid as extra values to product ids array
    $cat_array_result[] = array(
      'id' => $single_product_id,
      'type' => 'foreignid'
    );
  }

  // problem is after the first array the second get also the first array values
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($cat_array_result);
  echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
  Array 1
    (
        // this is are the correct product ids
        [0] => 45049917079
        [1] => 45056971449
    )

//with wrong id from previous array
    Array 2 
    (
        [0] => Array
            (    
                [id] => 44990952854
                [type] => foreignid
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (

                [id] => 45054787942
                [type] => foreignid
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (

                [id] => 45056971448
                [type] => foreignid
            )
    
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 45049917079
                [type] => foreignid
            )
    
        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 45056971449
                [type] => foreignid
            )
    
    )
```

As you can see in the loop of product ids, first array that are the correct ids that must be visible in the second array. I only want to add [type] => foreignid to the array for my JSON file

Comment: You're only adding to `$cat_array_results`, but not resetting it...

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment, how do i resetting it?

Comment: Before the second loop starts, write `$cat_array_results = [];`

Comment: I added it in the first loop, but it not work. i see it is result not results. Thanks!